# How to run the file directly in browser in APTANA?

Tags: php, ide, aptana

I have configured aptana with WAMP server,

But when I run the file it directly takes me to the index page of the project

**Ques: If I want to run some other page, say other.php on clicking on run icon directly how to open it in browser.**

example:

```
http://localhost/php_tutorial_2/index.php
```

If I remove the index.php, it takes me to the loscalhost directly

Screenshot of the run configuration of pho_tutorial_2

[image: run config screenshot]

Browser configuration for firefox is

[image: browser config]

Comment: Not an Aptana user, but as many (most?) php projects use a routing engine to control application flow, rather than loading individual php files directly, its quite logical that the run command simply loads the webroot (index.php) - thats the case with the IDE's i use

Comment: with dreamweaver .. we can directly open the page we are working.. its not a manual writing in the browser at all .

Comment: On the top image there is a box called `File` with a field called `Initial Script`. Just add the filename you want to run in there.

Comment: @RiggsFolly so everytime I need to click run, I have to change the file name .. this is the problem statement here what you said.

Comment: Sure, but dreamweaver hasnt really been updated since 2005. In most modern applications there is a single entrypoint into the application (usually index.php). There are many advantages to a single entrypoint, you would benefit from taking a modern approach

Comment: Failing that, click run once, then keep the browser open. Click refresh when you want to see changes. There is no compile step with php, clicking run is simply opening the browser and pointing it at your local address, nothing else.

Comment: Once you get past simple tutorials you will find that in most cases you will want to run your site from a single entrypoint (index.php) anyway to ensure that everything is as it should be when you get to the page you actually want to debug.

Comment: I agree that, I am not a dreamweaver fan, but it gives the flexibility to debug, open a single file, drag drop to DW, edit check and done for the day, So was just looking this flexi here as well .. np .